# On the definitions of $n$-manifold etc.

Tags: geometry, manifolds, definition, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm doing 3rd year undergraduate geometry (an introductory subject), and we've been given formal definitions of terms like "$n$-manifold" and "smooth $n$-manifold." However, I tend to think about these concepts in simplified terms. My simplified definitions are:

- An $n$-manifold is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n,$ regarded up to homeomorphism.
- A smooth $n$-manifold is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ that is locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n,$ regarded up to diffeomorphism.

**Question 0.** Are these definitions basically correct? If not, why not?

**Question 1.** Can the concept of a Riemannian $n$-manifold be given a "simplistic" definition like those above that is basically correct?

Comment: The "up to homeomorphism/diffeomorphim" parts are  incorrect; being optimistic, you are defining homeomorphism/diffeomorphism classes of manifolds, not manifolds. Also, in the smooth case, you need to have a previous definition of what it means for a subspace of $\mathbb R^k$ to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ (and for that you'll need... a definition of what a smooth manifold is)

Comment: Manifolds *a priori* do not have an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$, but there is a [deep theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) which says an $n$-manifold can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ so your definitions are technically correct (though it's generally advised to use as few conditions as possible in a definition, and to let the other conditions be theorems).

Comment: Riemannian manifolds can also be considered as submanifolds of some big $\Bbb R^N$ by the Nash embedding theorem (with the metric inherited from the canonical one on $\Bbb R^N$). I don't think there's anything gained by thinking of them this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuitive descriptions are fairly ok for most manifolds, if you replace "subspace" by "subset" and if your formal definition on manifold includes paracompactness and second-countability.  However, we do NOT identify homeomorphic topological manifolds or diffeomorphic smooth manifolds.  A smooth manifold is defined in terms of a maximal atlas with smooth transition functions and two smooth manifolds are equivalent if they have compatible atlases.  It is completely possible and frequent for two manifolds to NOT have compatible atlases (so have different smooth structures on them) but nevertheless be diffeomorphic.  The standard example can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33805/why-is-the-x-x1-3-atlas-on-r-diffeomorphic-with-the-x-x-atlas-on-r with detailed discussion.

Let me also note that although strong enough axioms guarantee that manifolds can be embedded into some finite-dimensional Euclidean space, it is actually better NOT to think of them as such.  This is because manifolds can be embedded in many spaces in many incompatible ways; building your intuition around one such embedding can lead to stumbling blocks when you need to embed them in other spaces or in different ways.

Comment: A subspac of $\mathbb R^n$ will be paracompact and second countable automatically.

Comment: But part of the question of the OP is whether it is legitimate to think of abstract manifolds as subspaces of Euclidean spaces.  I am telling him he can if they are paracompact and 2nd countable.  I did that because I don't know whether the definition of manifold in his class includes paracompactness and 2nd countability.